# How can I use Google Fit API to register the time in which the user is running?

Tags: android

I was trying to make a fitness app and I wanted to use Google Fit, I watched the code samples they provided in the documentation and managed to get the step count per day, but now I would like to make my app to register the starting time and end time between which the use ran. I really did not understand too much from the Sessions API, because I think that is the solution. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the following example? This is pretty much what you are after i believe

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistorySessions/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistorysessions/MainActivity.java#L227

Comment: I did, but it did not help me much, thanks for the replay.